# Hibernate asking for javax.validation.constraints.Size for enum

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, enums, dropwizard

Working with dropwizard and hibernate
Exception when I try to do a persist is

> No validator could be found for constraint
>   'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type
>   'enums.ServiceType'. Check configuration for 'type'

Code is below:

```
@Table(name = "transactions",
        indexes = {
                @Index(name = "references_index", columnList = "reference_id")
        }
)

public class Transaction {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "reference_id", unique = true)
    private String referenceId;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ServiceType type;

    @NonNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "provider")
    private String provider;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_date", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdTimeStamp;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_updated", insertable = false, updatable = true)
    private Date updatedTimeStamp;

    public Transaction(String referenceId, String state, ServiceType type, String provider) {
        this.referenceId = referenceId;
        this.state = state;
        this.type = type;
        this.provider = provider;
    }

}
```

where

```
public enum ServiceType {
    TYPEA, TYPEB, TYPEC
}
```

doing a persist in the DAO

```
class TransactionDAO extends AbstractDAO<Transaction> {
    /**
     * Creates a new DAO with a given session provider.
     *
     * @param sessionFactory a session provider
     */
    public TransactionDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        super(sessionFactory);
    }

      protected Transaction persistTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        return persist(transaction);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `@Valid` against my enum solves this. However I don't know why the error message said it was trying *javax.validation.constraints.Size*

code snippet from working code

```
 @NonNull
 @Valid
 @Column(name = "type")
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 private ServiceType type;
```